# Timeline Vis - Force Subgroup 2 to come after Subgroup 1 using subgroup ordering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, vis.js-timeline

I have a timeline where I have 3 subgroups 1, 2 and 3. In subgroup 2, I have 2 items named "B" and "BB". I created the timeline with custom subgroup ordering. In the output, I am getting BB on top, then items A and C below BB and finally B at the end, even when BB and B share the same subgroup 2. 
What I want instead is, A to come at the top, then B and BB clustered together below A and finally C at the end. Basically, I want the subgroups to always look like a cluster and be together in the timeline.

Link to the non-working example - [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a8xdhpac/57/)

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <div id="visualization"></div>
</body>
```

**JS**

```
function customSubgroupOrder(a, b) {
  return b.subgroup - a.subgroup;
}

var items = [{
  id: 1,
  group: "X",
  content: "A",
  subgroup: 1,
  start: "2016-01-01",
  end: "2016-01-31"
}, {
  id: 2,
  group: "X",
  content: "B",
  subgroup: 2,
  start: "2016-01-15",
  end: "2016-02-29"
}, {
  id: 4,
  group: "X",
  content: "BB",
  subgroup: 2,
  start: "2016-01-19",
  end: "2016-02-21"
}, {
  id: 3,
  group: "X",
  content: "C",
  subgroup: 3,
  start: "2016-02-15",
  end: "2016-02-29"
}];
var groups = [{
  id: "X",
  content: "Custom Ordering<br>Top-to-Bottom",
  subgroupOrder: customSubgroupOrder
}];
var options = {
  stack: true
};

var el = document.getElementById('visualization');
var timeline = new vis.Timeline(el, items, groups, options);
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `subgroupStack:true` option to the group `x` it will stack its subgroups on top of each. You can find a working demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rexzing/jsw7qyhm/1/).